# Prove $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\frac{\mathbb{E}(X^\epsilon)-1}{\epsilon}=\mathbb{E}(\log X)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

> Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable such that $\mathbb{E}(X^a)<+\infty$ for some $a>0.$ Prove that: $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\frac{\mathbb{E}(X^\epsilon)-1}{\epsilon}=\mathbb{E}(\log X).$$
>   Also, construct an example such that both members of the equality are equal to $-\infty.$

*Attempt.* Since X is non-negative, sequence $(X_n),$ where $X_n:= n(\sqrt[n]{X}-1)$, converges pointwise to $\log X$ as $n\to +\infty.$ Then eventually: 
$$X_n<\log X+1=\frac{1}{a}\,\log X^a+1<\frac{1}{a}\,X^a+1$$
where: 
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{a}\,X^a+1\right) =\frac{1}{a}\,\mathbb{E}(X^a)+1<+\infty.$$ By dominating convergence theorem we get: 
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\mathbb{E}\big(n(\sqrt[n]{X}-1)\big)=\mathbb{E}(\log X).$$
Since $$\epsilon \mapsto \frac{\mathbb{E}(X^\epsilon)-1}{\epsilon}=
\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X^\epsilon-1}{\epsilon}\right)$$
is increasing in terms of $\epsilon$, we get that:
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\frac{\mathbb{E}(X^\epsilon)-1}{\epsilon}=
\lim_{n \to +\infty}\mathbb{E}\big(n(\sqrt[n]{X}-1)\big)=\mathbb{E}(\log X).$$

1) Is the above procedure correct?

2)  "*Since X is non-negative $\ldots$ converges pointwise to $\log X$*"
holds for $X>0$ (at least, almost surely). 
How do we treat the case where $\mathbb{P}(X=0)>0$? In that case $\log X=-\infty?$

3) My  example cannot be a random variable uniformely distributed on $(0,1]$ (since in that case $\mathbb{E}(\log X)=\int_0^1\log x\mathrm{d}x=-1\neq -\infty.$

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Eventually '$X_n <\frac  1a X^{a}+1$' is not valid argument. How large you have to take $n$ to be varies with the sample point $\omega$.

Comment: Previously asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1934500/321264.