# Example of random variable such that $\displaystyle \lim_{p \to 0^+} \mathbb {E} ((X^p-1)/p ) = \mathbb{E} (\log X)=-\infty.$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

> Construct an example of a non-negative random variable on a probability space such that both members of equality  $\displaystyle \lim_{p \to 0^+} \mathbb {E} ((X^p-1)/p ) = \mathbb{E} (\log X)$ are equal to $-\infty.$

*Attempt*. Equality follows from [Show that $\lim_{p \to 0} \mathbb {E} [(X^p-1)/p ] = \mathbb{E} [\log X]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934500/show-that-lim-p-to-0-mathbb-e-xp-1-p-mathbbe-log-x). 
If $X$ was uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, then $\displaystyle \mathbb{E} (\log X)=\int\limits_0^1\log x\,\mathrm{d}x=-1\neq -\infty$, so $X$ cannot be an example as wanted.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could just have the random variable which takes value $0$ almost surely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ take the values $\frac 1 n$ with probability $\frac c {n (\log n)^{2}}$ for $n=2,3,...$ where $c$ is chosen such that $\sum \frac c {n (\log n)^{2}}=1$. Then $E\log X=-\infty$.

I am using the facts that $\sum \frac 1 {n(\log n)^{2}} <\infty$ whereas $\sum \frac 1 {n(\log n)} =\infty$